# Can not get user info from Identity Server 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver3, openid-connect

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Identity-Server-3-Standalone-Implementation-Part-1) tutorial of creating Identity Server wit ha hybrid flow client. It is all good till I reach the point for fetching user info through the user info endpoint.

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
{
    AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
    {
        var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(new Uri(Constants.UserInfoEndpoint).ToString());
        var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync(n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);

        identity.AddClaims(userInfoResponse.Claims);

        n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
    }
}
```

I get a compile error at the point where adding claims: `identity.AddClaims(userInfoResponse.Claims);`

The errors area actually two. The when when pointing to the arguments says:

> Argument type
>   'System.Collections.Genereic.IEnumerable
>   [mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]' is not assignable to parameter type
>   ' [mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]'

And the other one, when pointing the method name says:

> The type 'Claim' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You
>   must add reference to an assembly 'System.Security.Claims,
>   Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=503f5..'

I tried to add a reference to this assembly through nuget but then another conflict started to happen. There was ambiguous reference for System.Security.Claims between IdentityProvider and mscorlib.

What to do in order to achieve my goal of assigning user claims to the identity of the logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the tutorial, this line:

```
identity.AddClaims(userInfoResponse.Claims);
```

must be changed with this:

```
identity.AddClaims(userInfoResponse.GetClaimsIdentity().Claims);
```

Your second compiler error arises by the using of `Claim` type without specifying the namespace. Identify where you are using `Claim` explicitly and add the correct namespace to it.

**Note:**

this: `userInfoResponse.GetClaimsIdentity().Claims` is equivalent to:

```
userInfoResponse.Claims.Select(c => new System.Security.Claim(c.Item1, c.Item2))
```

Comment: userInfoResponse doesn't contain a definition for 'GetClaimsIdentity'

Comment: `GetClaimsIdentity` is an [extension method](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel/blob/master/source/IdentityModel.Net45/Client/UserInfoResponseExtensions.cs). I suspect you are not using the correct nuget package for `IdentityModel`. Be aware that there are two different packages: `Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client` which is the deprecated one and `IdentityModel` (version 2.8.0) which is the correct one but does not contain the extension method in the newer versions.

Comment: I am using 'OpenID Connect & OAuth 2.0 client library', version 2.8.0 of IdentityModel

Comment: The tutorial you are referring to is using an older version of the library (possibily the `1.X` branch). You either have to use the old version or change your code accordingly (in version 2.8.0 `Claims` property should return already an `IEnumerable<System.Security.Claims>`)